# I wonder if angle gradient is possible

Tags: objective-c, nsbezierpath, radial-gradients

I´m doing some testing on gradients using NSBezierPath and make some progress so far with **radial** gradients. see first picture. I wonder, however, if it is possible to make **angle** gradients as in picture 2.

Anyone done this?

### Tia, Ronald

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa has no public API for angular gradients.  You'll have to do it yourself by painting pixels in varying colors.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question!
There is no Standard Feature. 
Try to approx by dividing the Circle into sectors which functions as clipping Polygon
Then draw a linear Gradient in direction 90 degrees to the Center line of the sectors.